# Evaluation order (commutativity/associativity) of ANDed terms in Postgres WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization, execution-plan, postgresql-performance

Is Postgres' query planner able to rearrange terms in a `WHERE` clause according to the rules of commutativity and associativity?

For example, do the following `WHERE` clauses all result in a query plan of the same approximate time-complexity?:

- `WHERE a AND b AND c`
- `WHERE (a AND b) AND c`
- `WHERE a AND (b AND c)`
- `WHERE (c AND b) AND a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the optimizer rearranges the `WHERE` conditions as it thinks fit, and all your examples will result in the same execution plan.

Comment: Thanks, but this gets more complicated if I make this a conjunction of disjunctions. Does the query planner internally reduce a complex WHERE phrase into disjunctive normal form, or similar?

Comment: Within certain limits, the optimizer will attempt logical transformations to find an efficient plan. But the intelligence is limited, because it has to be fast. Sometimes, you will have to rewrite the statement. When in doubt, use `EXPLAIN`.